# Scraping with Javascript within Client Browsers

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Scraping websites with PHP or Java is easily implemented, my question is however if I would want to have the client computer scrape, if I could do this with javascript rather than on the server side.

The background is that websites could block my servers or server farms, however if I let the user computer scrape and then post that information to my server we would avoid that blockage of the servers.

1. Can we scrape a website with javascript and use CSS selectors or regular expressions to parse the HTML in order to extract certain information?
2. Will we be able to protect our code that we use in the javacript or will our scraping algorithm have to be human readable to people?
3. If we then post the results via AJAX to our server, how do we make sure it was our script and not manipulated data by a malevolent user?

Is there a good framework for accomplishing this or should I continue server-side scraping?

Comment: There is a variable containing the html of the body, it is `document.body.innerHTML`. See if you could use this to your advantage. You can use jQuery to find data based on css selectors, and regex is built in to JavaScript

Comment: 1. Same Origin Policy. 2. Not really. 3. No full proof way